# How to install a plugin for the elasticsearch kubernetes cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, elasticsearch-plugin

I have a working kubernetes cluster with the elasticsearch up and running returning a 200. I am trying to install the HQ plugin. So i log into the node running the es-client, and attach to the docker container. When i execute the command

```
/ # /elasticsearch/bin/plugin  -install royrusso/elasticsearch-HQ
```

i am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'DISCOVERY_SERVICE'
```

I am using the yaml files from here
https://github.com/pires/kubernetes-elasticsearch-cluster
with these modifications
https://github.com/UKHomeOffice/docker-elasticsearch/blob/master/examples/kubernetes.md

Am i missing something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Attach to the container

```
docker exec -it 9f13966b1201 /bin/sh
```

Export the DISCOVERY_SERVICE

```
export DISCOVERY_SERVICE=${DISCOVERY_SERVICE:-elasticsearch-discovery}
```

Install the Plugin

```
/elasticsearch/bin/plugin  -install royrusso/elasticsearch-HQ
```

keep in mind this will not be persistent

Comment: Don't you have to restart the service after installing the plugin?

Comment: Is service restart required for the plugin changes to be reflected?

Answer (score 0):

```
command: 
            - '/bin/sh'
            - '-c'
            - 'logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-kubernetes && logstash -f /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf'
```

You can use this in the Deployment|StatefulSet under image section.